# How to concatenate yml files into one file?

Tags: c++, opencv

How to concatenate many `.YML` descriptor files into one `.YML` file that contains all of them. I want to use `Kmeans` for clustering the data.

Comment: `cv::kmeans` takes matrix as an argument anyways. And - doesn't just reading all the data from different `.yml`s and writing it to a single one do what you need?

Comment: Agree - lot easier to merge them in memory.

Comment: so, what can i do :( !! i have a lot of images !!1 so how can i gather all their descriptors in a Matrix !! so i can use it as an argument in kmeans !!! if anyone has a suggestions , because its my first time i use opencv and i dont have lot of time left !!

Comment: my idea is to gather all the descriptors in .yml files then merge them in one !! then i laod this file in a cv::Mat !!!

Comment: if there is an easier idea !! suggest it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileStorage fileToSave("your_new_file_here", FileStorage::WRITE);


for...

Mat dataToBeSave;
FileStorage 1("yourfilehere", FileStorage::READ);

f1["your_data_name"] >> dataToBeSave;
f1.release();

fileToSave << "your_tag_for_your_data" << dataToBeSave;

... //endfor

fileToSave.release();
```

Comment: FileStorage fileToSave("newFile.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
Mat dataToBeSave;
FileStorage f1("1.yml", FileStorage::READ);

f1["descriptors1"] >> dataToBeSave;
f1.release();

fileToSave << "Newdata" << dataToBeSave;


fileToSave.release();

Comment: after using your code, i get an empty new file , i dont know why !! ? could you please clarify more !!

Comment: Sure Doudou, but you need to add new tags to each new data you want to save.

Comment: You must be sure that you are collecting the right tag from your old file. You can open your .YML with Notepad++ and check.

Comment: You can fully understand YML acessing [YML & OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)

Comment: what do you mean by tags ? i dont know what it is, can you write a piece of code to clarify it !!

Comment: i am reading your link , and i ll reply u if i did understand !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried load your *.YML files and save all the information to a new one.

What I suggest you to do is to code a FOR loop to open all your file and save the data into a new *.YML file unifying all your data in a single file.

Comment: i already extracted all my *yml and saved them, but i donno how to merge them and how to control its data !! so could you please provide me with a piece of code of this loop !!

Comment: i want later also to load this *yml file in a cv::Mat !! to use it later as an input in a funtion !!

Comment: How to load your YML data into a cv::Mat
'FileStorage fDataset;
Mat myMat;
fDataset.open( "C:/myfile.yml", FileStorage::READ);
fDataset["mytag"] >> myMat;'